# Adding dictionary words list to deoplete plugin

Tags: neovim, autocompletion, dictionary, plugin-deoplete

Let's say I have a list of words in one file in my home directory (each word is in a separate line):

```
bar
barfoo
foo
foobar
...
```

How can I add this list of words to Vim deoplete auto-completion plugin? I've tried this solution without any results:

```
set dictionary=/path/to/wordsList.txt
call deoplete#custom#source('dictionary', 'min_pattern_length', 4)
```

**Bonus Question**: Can I configure `deoplate` to autocomplete words from all opened buffers (not the only one I'm currently editing)?

Answer (score 0):

Caution: I don't use it and can't (most of my installations come without `+python3` feature, and I sometimes I even have Python on the plateform). I'm writing based on [the documentation](https://github.com/Shougo/deoplete.nvim/blob/master/doc/deoplete.txt).

First, according to `:h deoplete-external-sources`, you need to install (if it is not already the case) also [`deoplete-dictionary`](https://github.com/deoplete-plugins/deoplete-dictionary).

Second, you cannot get results for `bar` and `foo` with your setting which is filtering for words that are more than 3 characters only:

```
call deoplete#custom#source('dictionary', 'min_pattern_length', 4)
```

Regarding you bonus question, `:h deoplete-source-buffer` says that it's using also “the current tabpage windows buffers and the opened buffers which have same 'filetype'.” And you can make it collect keywords from buffers of any filetype by setting `require_same_filetype` to False. I'm afraid you can do no more than that.